# Suppose that $\lim_{x\to \infty} x_n = x$. Show that x is a point of accumulation of E.

Tags: real-analysis

> Let E be a set and {$x_n$} a sequence of distinct elements of E. Suppose that $$\lim_{x\to ∞} x_n = x$$ Show that x is a point of accumulation of E.

let {$x_n$} be a sequence of distinct elements of E such that $\lim_{x\to ∞} x_n = x$.
Then x = $x_m$ for at most one m ∈ N; hence, there is $N_1$ ∈ N such that $x_n$ ~= x for all
n ≥ $N_1$. Let ε > 0 be given. Then since $x_n$ → x as n → ∞, there is $N_2$ ∈ N such that |$x_n$ − x| < ε for all n ≥ N2.
So if we let n = max{$N_1, N_2$}, we have 0 < |$x_n$ − x| < ε. Hence, x is an accumulation point of E.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking; are you looking for verification (if so, please tag as [tag:proof-verification])? Also, please state your definition of accumulation point.

Answer (score 2):

An easier method of proof: a definition of convergence that you might have been given is

> $x_n \to x$ if (and only if) for every $\varepsilon>0$, $B(x,\varepsilon)$ contains the element $x_n$ for all but finitely many $n \in \Bbb N$.

Or more simply

> $x_n \to x$ if (and only if) every (open) neighborhood of $x$ contains the element $x_n$ for all but finitely many $n \in \Bbb N$.

Compare that to the definition of an accumulation point:

> $x$ is an accumulation point of $A$ if every neighborhood of $x$ contains some $a \in A$ with $a \neq x$